# Can't open nano and can't install it on Ubuntu Server 14

Tags: system-installation, nano

I'm having a lot of trouble getting up and running Ubuntu Server. I just installed it on VMware and it appears it doesn't have nano. When I run `sudo nano /etc/hosts` it says "-bash nano: command not found" and when I try `sudo apt-get install nano` it says

> Media change: please insert the disc labelled 'Ubuntu Server 14.04.2
>   LTS *Trusty Tahr* - release amd64 in the drive '/media/cdrom/` and
>   press enter

This is a fresh install so if I messed something up with it I'd rather start again. I thought nano came with Ubuntu, did I select something wrong?

Comment: “media change: please insert the disc labeled” when trying to install Ruby on Rails [duplicate] http://askubuntu.com/questions/386265/media-change-please-insert-the-disc-labeled-when-trying-to-install-ruby-on-ra

Comment: Does nano run **without** sudo? if yes, it could indicate that your sudoers `secure_path` is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have some how been missed when installing the OS initially. I tried re installing and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm out on a limb here, but it is probably simply a matter of 1. `nano` not being installed and 2. misconfigured package sources.

You can try the following:

1. Comment the cdrom-related line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding a # in front of it, like

`# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main`

2. Make sure you do have a Trusty repository in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g.

`deb http://somemirror.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main`

`deb-src http://somemirror.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main`

`deb http://somemirror.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main`

`deb-src http://somemirror.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main`

3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install nano`

(Of course for this to work you'll have to rely on some *other* editor, I'm guessing `vi` or if you don't even have `vi` resort to some creative `cat`'ting and piping).

Comment: For `deb` and `deb-src` it says command not found

Comment: @Celeritas, those are not commands, you have to make sure you have those lines or something to that effect in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Note that you have to replace `somemirror` with, well, some mirror - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors. If you are not sure copy your `sources.list` file to a USB drive and post it here.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be the line relating to `cdrom` in your `sources.list` file. You can delete this line completely with

```
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But perhaps it would be better (editor speaking here) to comment out the line to avoid too much destruction and make a backup in case you need it

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/cdrom/ s/^/#/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```